# Should we add language tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

As a non native English speaker I sometimes will have the requirement for software to be in my native language (German). Now there are many languages and for most of us (techs) its okay if the language is English and most likely the English speakers are the largest community here.

So, should we add any language tags? Only one (`Non-english`, `translateable`... suggestions?) Should we add one for each language?

<sup>If you think we should not have any please add an answer saying so instead of downvoting the question</sup>

Comment: Angelo: It is SE Policy to indeicate agreement with a meta post by downvoting the question. This is why you don't have Rep on meta. See my post on this http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64/meta-reputation/8175#8175
Why is your question special?

Comment: @Oxinabox My question does not state a thing that can be agreed / disagreed to. I'm not proposing a state but asking what states are there. I've seen downvotes on similar questions where its unclear what a downvote mean (bad question? irrelevant aspect?) cause they don't say what the op prefers. I wanted to make sure that 'yay' and 'nay' indications go to the answers where they are meaningful in this context.

Comment: @Oxinabox Also: did you mean "indicate disagreement by downvoting?" cause the opposite would be quite unintuitive :)

Comment: Opps yes i meant indicate disagreement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This to me sounds more like a specific requirement that should be spelled out in the body of the request rather than a tag in the system. If you need multi-language support, just state in the question. It would get somewhat unwieldy to start creating tags for all the personal requirements of a software request. It should just be stated in the question.

I really don't see a need to add this as an explicit tag.

Comment: The idea is that when I come to the site and want to search for software (before asking myself) -> Should I then be able to specify my language requirement as tag or not?

Comment: But that's only one specific requirement folks might be looking for. It's been suggested before that we create this *giant* matrix of feature comparisons so <fill-in-your-criteria> just pops up what you are looking for. I think that is an impossibly broad task that will not work all that well anyway. Software recommendations aren't about mechanics; it's about personal experience. Sooner or later it is simply better to just "talk" to someone. That's why I don't like ***over*** tagging questions as a way to drill down into overly-rigorous specifics.

Comment: I agree. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Many products offer multiple language support. A [multi-language] tag might be fine for the need of such a product.

Other products are even different, depending on the language. Or you need a software especially in that language. Then there might be the need of specific language tags like [german].

Answer (score 1):

I think that language tags is a good idea.

- They should be optional
- Given that the majority of our user population are English speakers a tag for English is probably unnecessary.